# Move plots between axes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am playing around with a Matlab gui. I have a function, that I feed 4 empty plots, and as it runs, each plot is updated with something like

```
set(hplot1, 'xData', updatedData)
drawnow
```

So before I call this function I create 4 blank plots with

```
handles.myplot1 = bar(NaN)
...
```

The function then runs on a button press and the plots are updated. However I only have 1 axes in the gui and would like to switch between which plot is shown. How can I go about this?

Lastly is there a way to create a blank `surfc` similar to what I did with `bar(NaN)`? Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
set(hplot1, 'Parent', handles.axes1);
```

should work.

Setting the parent appears to be what I was looking for. Although I have an older version of matlab on my home machine so my gui won't actually run and I can't test it until tomorrow.

edit: This should work, but now my problem is creating blank plots without deleting the previous plot.

edit2: To create the plots I just use

```
a = figure(1); set(a, 'Visible', 'off')
handles.plot1 = bar()
b = figure(2); set(b, ...
```